# Can we use Watson Knowledge Studio model to improve Watson Discovery Service Query Capability, especially on Natural Language Query?

Tags: service, ibm-watson

Can you tell me how to use Watson Knowledge Studio model improve Watson Discovery Service query ability. I am not sure WKS model can work on the way of Natural Language or Discovery Query Language or both? If it can work on both, how can we get the direct-viewing effects? By confidence or other parameters? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely add entity and relation enrichments by applying a custom model to improve or more appropriately customize Watson Discovery Service. Train your model in WKS and deploy in discovery, then go to discovery top right - click configure data and go to enrichments tab. Add entity and relation and enter your deployed custom model id from WKS and apply. I hope it should help your discovery service to be customized.